# ordering 2m student in k classes with m seats each

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I have $2m$ student, $m$ girls and $m$ boys, and I want to order them in $k$ classes with $m$ capacity of each class, so there will be at least one girl in each class. I calculate it by inclusion-exclusion principle:

$$w(0) = P_{km}^{2m}$$

$P_i\:-\text{in the i class there isn't a girl}$

So, as I understand,  for $w(r)$ I choose $\binom kr$
 classes that will not have a girl, then $P_{m\left(k-r\right)}^m$ ordering the girls in all other classes, then ordering the boys in all classes $P_{mk}^m$
So: $$w\left(r\right)=\binom krP_{m\left(k-r\right)}^mP_{mk}^m$$

But the right answer for $w(r)$ is:
$$w\left(r\right)=\binom krP_{m\left(k-r\right)}^mP_{m\left(k-1\right)}^m$$
I don't see why it should be $m(k-1)$ in the last expression. 
Generally, the next step is:$$E\left(0\right)=\left(-1\right)^rw\left(r\right)$$
but that isn't the issue. Cam somebody explain it to me please?

Comment: Your notations are confusing. For writing $\binom kr$, you should write `\binom kr` instead of `\left(_r^k\right)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll notice it next time, seems you already redact it. Anything about the solution )?

Comment: it isn't mentioned, but I guess k <= m, otherwise if k > m, the answer is 0, and it isn't the case.

Comment: I know the solution by inclusion and exclusion its right, the second which I wrote with k-1, don't you know what the reason for it? 
Because this is the solution given in the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation for permutations is also confusing (to me), so instead of confusing you further with my notation, I'll just explain simply.

You are seating all the $m$ girls first, so seats remaining in which boys can be permuted is $mk - m = m(k-1)$

Comment: Very clear (and trivial), thank you

Comment: You're welcome, sometimes trivial things escape the greatest minds, like the story of Newton, cat and kitten !